# Finding all cycles of a certain length in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Hello,

I'm looking for a formula or algorithm to find the number of cycles of a certain length $k$ in a graph.

I know that $(A^k)_{ii}$ gives me the number of cycles from vertex $i$ to itself ($A$ is the adjacency matrix), but these are cycles that might contain the same vertex twice.

I have to tried to devise some sort of a recurrence formula but to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you do some inclusion/exclusion if you know every cycle length?


Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your graph topologically planar or non-planar, weighted or unweighted, directed or undirected?
Do you want an algorithm and/or a formula/bound?

For bounds on planar graphs, see [Alt et al. On the number of simple cycles in planar graphs](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1731975)

For an algorithm, see the following paper.  It incrementally builds k-cycles from (k-1)-cycles and (k-1)-paths without going through the rigourous task of computing the cycle space for the entire graph.  It also handles duplicate avoidance.

- Hongbo Liu; Jiaxin Wang; , *"A new
  way to enumerate cycles in graph*,"
  Telecommunications, 2006. AICT-ICIW
  '06. International Conference on
  Internet and Web Applications and
  Services/Advanced International
  Conference on , vol., no., pp. 57-
  57, 19-25 Feb. 2006 doi:
  10.1109/AICT-ICIW.2006.22 URL: http://www.ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1602189&isnumber=33674

Answer (score 1):

If you consider only simple cycles (every vertex visited at most once) then this problem is NP-complete, so no polynomial (in $|G|$ and $k$) algorithm is known.

If non-polynomial algorithms are ok, you can use dynamic programming algorithm with complexity $O(\sum_{i=0}^{i\le k}\binom{n}{i}n^2)$. This algorithm calculates for every subset $S$ of at most $k$ vertices and every vertex $v \in S$ from this subset the number of paths that goes through all vertices from $S$ and has $v$ as the last vertex.

Comment: Is this algorithm better than enumerating the $k$-tuples of vertices and seeing if they are the vertices of a cycles in the given order?

Comment: The number of $k$-tuples with distinct elements is $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ which for big $k$ is much more than the number of subsets with at most $k$ elements. For example if $n=k$ then this algorithm works in time $O(n^2 2^n)$ and enumerating algorithm in time $O(n!)$.

Comment: I see where our discrepancies lie: I had interpreted the question as fixing a certain value of *k*, whereas you are not doing this. For a *fixed* value of *k*, enumerating *k*-tuples seems to have complexity $O(\binom{n}{k})=O(n^k)$.

Comment: Yes, if $k$ is fixed and we are interested only how time complexity depends on $n$ then both algorithms have the same complexity. They actually differ by a factor of $k!$.